# Create an array of specific type depending on condition

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a switch case on some `enum` type depending on which I am creating an array.
It looks like:

```
switch (type) {
    case BOOLEAN:
        Boolean[] booleans = new Boolean[];
    case STRING:
        String[] strings = new String[];
}
```

I wonder is it possible to extract it to some method so it works like:

```
ArrayWrapper arrayWrapper = // some logic for which I am looking for
```

and then I have a generic method that accepts any type of array, and I would like to invoke it like
`method(arrayWrapper.getArray());` and it will be casted to specific type and processed by specific type processor?

Comment: nope, not really. Arrays can't be of a generic type - you can declare one like that, but you can't create one.

Comment: Are you looking for an `Object[]` there?

Comment: Fully not sure what you're trying to do. (What's the relation to the "java-stream" tag?!) So you have an enum that defines which type of array *you* will create, so at that point *you* know what type the array is. Then you lose the information from the enum and later want to try and reconstruct it to basically do the same `switch(type)` on the array instances again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Java Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) combined with the [Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) can be used in order to obtain an instance of `T[]`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T[] createArrayInstance(Class<T> clazz, int size) {
    return (T[])Array.newInstance(clazz, size);
}
```

If you want to store, for any reason, a value in the resulting array:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T[] createArrayInstance(T obj) {
    T[] a = (T[])Array.newInstance(obj.getClass(), 1);//or whatever size you want
    a[0] = obj;
    return a;
}
```

See also: [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

The [`java.lang.reflect.Array`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) class provides functionality for working with any type of arrays, without knowing what type it is.

Using that class, you can write code like this:

```
public void example(Class<?> elemType) {
    Object[] arr = (Object[]) Array.newInstance(elemType, 10);

    // Do something with the array
}
```

(Don't cast to `Object[]` if you want to be able to work with arrays of primitive types.)

`Array` is part of the reflection system. That implies that you will have to used `Class` objects for element types, and probably have variables of `Object` type to refer to element values.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way would be to bind the array's element type to a generic type parameter and tie the processor and the array together early on:

```
public class ArrayProcessingWrapper<T> {
  private final T[] array;
  private final ArrayProcessor<T> processor;

  public ArrayProcessingWrapper(T[] array, ArrayProcessor<T> processor) {
    super();
    this.array = array;
    this.processor = processor;
  }

  public void processArray() {
    this.processor.process(this.array);
  }

}
```

Another way might be along the lines of functions

```
public abstract class Processor<T> {
  private final Supplier<T[]> arraySupplier;

  public Processor(final Supplier<T[]> arraySupplier) {
    super();
    this.arraySupplier = arraySupplier;
  }

  public T[] createArray() {
    return this.arraySupplier.get();
  }

  public void processNewArray() {
    this.doProcess(this.createArray());
  }

  protected abstract void doProcess(T[] data);
}

public class BooleanProcessor extends Processor<Boolean> {
  public BooleanProcessor(Supplier<Boolean[]> arraySupplier) {
    super(arraySupplier);
  }

  @Override
  protected void doProcess(Boolean[] data) {
    // Do fancy boolean stuff...
  }
}
```

But also have a look at `Iterable<E>` and/or `Collection<E>` (of which `ArrayList<E>` is what behaves the most like an array) instead of arrays.

To me, it seems like a design flaw if you need to use different logic ("processors") depending on the (runtime) type of an array.